# How can I get my score in an other class? JAVA

Tags: java, class

I'm making a game with multiple asteroids going down. The goal is to dodge as many asteroids for as long as you can. I made it so that as soon as an asteroid reaches the bottom of the screen it is send back up, now i want to count every time it gets to the bottom and add it to the score. 
My problem is that all the asteroids are the same class so if I use:

`if(y>700){
    y=-50;                        //
    x= (int) (Math.random()*670); // To send the asteroid back up
    setLocation(x,y);             //
    score++;                   // To add up the score
    System.out.println(score); // To print the score`

Every asteroid adds op his own amount of times it has reached the bottom, but I want to know how many asteroids have reached the bottom in total. So I figured I have to get the score out of the asteroid class and add it up in an other class but I don't know how.

This is the code of the asteroid class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Astroid extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
 public int yVelocity = 1;
 public int x = (int) (Math.random()*650), y = (int) (Math.random()*-1000);
 public Timer timer;
 private int score;

 public Astroid(int x,int y)
 {
    this.setLocation(x, y);
    this.setSize(25, 25);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setVisible(true);
 }
 {
    this.timer = null;
    this.timer = new Timer(10,new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            setLocation(x,(y+=yVelocity));
            timer.setDelay(10);
            repaint();

            if(y>700){
                y=-50;
                x= (int) (Math.random()*670);
                setLocation(x,y);

                score++;
                System.out.println(score);
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
 }
}
```

This is the code of the class that creates the asteroids:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SterTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

public int a;

public SterTest() 
{
    this.setSize(700, 700);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    final JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p.setLayout(null);

    for(a=0;a<3;a++) {
        Astroid astroid = new Astroid(1,1);
        p.add(astroid);
    } //Creates 3 asteroids to start with

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Astroid astroid2 = new Astroid(1,1);
            p.add(astroid2);    
            a++;
            System.out.println("Het aantal asteroids in game is:"+a);
        }               
    }, 5000, 5000); // creates a new asteroid every 5 seconds or so

    this.add(p);

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You might actually have to provide some addresability between your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: There are better and more OO approaches to this. This answer is that fastest route to working code from your current solution.**

Declare score as static.

```
private static int score
```

This will give you a single copy of that variable.

**However**

I see you have some threads. In this case you're going to need a little bit of synchronization to keep score consistent.

I recommend adding

```
private static final Object scoreLock
```

to your fields. And replace `score++` with

```
synchronized(scoreLock)
{
    Asteroid.score++;
}
```

Comment: `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {` Each of your asteroids run concurrently. This means that it's possible that one of the asteroids could retrieve the score value. Then execution may pass to another asteroid, and it can retrieve the SAME value. Now they both add 1 to the original value and the net effect is +1 to score when it should be +2. Granted, this would be a rare occurrence, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Using a static variable would work, but it probably isn't the responsibility of the `Astroid` class to manage the score of the game. If new ways to score get added to the game then it gets difficult to have the Astroid class manage score for the other things.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of the score probably isn't the job of the `Asteroid` class, so that variable would be best kept in a more central class. Then you can add an instance of the central class to each asteroid, and call a method to increment the score. Something like this:

```
public class ScoreKeeper {
    private AtomicInteger score;
    public void incrementScore (int points) {
        score.getAndAdd (points);
    }
    public int getScore () {
        return score.get ();
    }
}
```

In you class `SterTest` you would create a single instance of `ScoreKeeper` and pass it to each new `Astroid` instance you create.

```
public class Astroid {
    private ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper;
    public Astroid(int x,int y, ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper) {
        //... existing code ...
        this.scoreKeeper = scoreKeeper;
    }
    // ... when you want to increment the score, do this:
    scoreKeeper.incrementScore (1);
}
```

Comment: +1 (There is a disclaimer on my answer btw). I would change `incrementScore` to a synchronized method. His asteroids all have their own thread.

Comment: Ah, I missed the thread, thanks for pointing that out. I saw your disclaimer, though, I was just pointing out why it wasn't the best long-term solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to miss the thread. The OP's solution isn't particularly scalable. At about 30 asteroids he'll probably notice glitchy behaviour. I would have a single thread that moves all of the asteroids at once.

Comment: @Cruncher How would that work? I have just started with java, pleas teach me.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen It may be out of the scope of this question. But in a few sentences you maintain a List (ArrayList probably). And you start a thread that has a "while(true)" loop. At each iteration of this loop, you loop through your list of asteroids and call a method on it to tell it to do something. Then you do some kind of sleep to maintain a constant frame rate. Now to add an asteroid you just need to add it to the List. This requires a fair bit of synchronization too. If you attempt something, you can post a new question asking how you can do this without 1 thread per asteroid.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen if you do make a new question, notify me here. I may be able to provide a decent answer for it.

Comment: Getting past the asteroids is going to be the only way to score (for now at least) so I don't know if I should make a whole new class for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in keeping score of an individual asteroid than there is no reason to add a `score` variable to that class.  The score should be maintained at a higher level, perhaps in your SterTest() class.  When you detect an asteroid has made it to the bottom, just increment that score.  I don't want to tell you how to design your program, but the most obvious way would be to just have actionPerformed return the score.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AsteroidListener` interface.  Maybe like this:

```
public interface AsteroidListener {
   public void impact(Asteroid asteroid);
}
```

Make your `SterTest` class implement this interface.  Add a new parameter to your Asteroid constructor, for the listener.

```
public Asteroid(int x, int y, AsteroidListener listener) { }
```

When you need to call the listener to notify it that there was an impact:

```
listener.impact(this);
```

Tally up the score in your SterTest class.

Comment: This is probably better, but you're going to need synchronization in any case. As it stands if 2 asteroids "impact" at the same time there's a small chance that one of the scores won't get counted

Comment: In no time the asteroids are falling with so much that the player won't notice any score loss to impact on the same time

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)/[Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) pattern:

```
public class Score extends Observable {
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    public void increment() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(Integer.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()));
    }
}
```

This class is added to `Astroid` :

```
public Astroid(Score score, int x,int y) {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // ...
        score.increment();
    }
}
```

`StarTest` implements the `Observer` interface:

```
public class StarTest implements Observer {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Integer count = (Inter)arg;
        // do something with the score
    }
}
```

You connect `Observer` and `Observable` as follows:

```
StarTest starTest = new StarTest();

Score score = new Score();
score.addObserver(starTest);

Astroid astroid = new Astroid(score, x, y);
```